# AQL or REST API Artifactory to remove empty folders

Tags: api, rest, continuous-integration, artifactory

I have to remove empty folders from Artifactory. The preferred way to do that was changing rules in AQL, but as far as I know, it's not possible to do it without removing non-empty Artifactory folders. I tried to add type rules as follow:

```
"type": {"$eq":"any"}
```

Also, I cannot add plugins to Artifactory API, so I can't use [Empty Folder Clean-up](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/empty-folder-clean-up/)
Finally, I was trying to use curl with [REST API Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API) to list all folders with paths and pull these that haven't any subfolders, something like:

```
curl -u "${username}":"$password" -X GET "<url>/artifactory/api/storage/<repo>/jenkins/artifacts?list&deep=1&listFolders=1" | jq '.file
s[].uri' | awk -F '"' '{ print $2 }' | awk -F '/' '{ print $2 }' | sort | uniq -c
```

And remove folders that don't have subfolders (children). But I'm not sure that it's the best idea. Do you have some suggestions on how Could I do it better and more effectively? Or maybe some other ideas?
 Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: I can try to create a JFrog CLI plugin that deletes empty folders and publish it here - https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-plugins-reg - If you think this will be helpful to you, please let me know and I'll create it.

Comment: @EyalBenMoshe thank you for your reply! If you could I would be really grateful :)

Comment: I'll work on this jfrog-cli plugin then. I'll share an update here soon.

Comment: Work in progress - https://github.com/eyalbe4/jfrog-cli-plugins/tree/rm-empty/rm-empty - still some more work to be done before it's ready.

Comment: PR created and will probably be reviewed soon - https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-plugins/pull/58

Answer (score 0):

There is this [User Plugin](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/cleanup/deleteEmptyDirs) to delete the empty directories that you can use to remove the empty folders.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot add plugins to Artifactory API...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [rm-empty](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-plugins/tree/main/rm-empty) JFrog CLI Plugin to remove empty folders from a specific path in Artifactory. The plugin is registered on the [JFrog CLI Plugins Registry](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-plugins-reg).